# Pom parent property is not being passed to child pom using Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm running into a strange issue.

I have a multi-module maven project and in the pom parent I have a property called `<build.number>` whose default value is `latest`, then, in a submodule I'm using this property to be part of a docker image tag. Tagging the docker image works fine. Then I use the same property in an other submodule to replace one field in a `deployment.yaml` file.

So in one module I tag the image an in the other I am pointing to that tagged image.

When I package the pom parent like this:

```
mvn clean package -Dbuild.number=1
```

it works fine. The last part of the image tag is `-1` and the deployment file is replaced correctly.

What is the issue?

The issue arises when I package the project with Jenkins. I have a multibranch jenkins pipeline. When executing the jenkins pipeline it runs a mvn command like this:

```
mvn clean package -Dbuild.numer=${BUILD_NUMER}
```

`${BUILD_NUMER}` should come from Jenkins.

After the execution, the image is tagged correctly but the field in the `deployment.yaml` file is replaced but the value is `latest`, the default value.

This is causing trouble because in the deployment file I must reference the right image. Having this reference pointing to `latest` it is pointing to a wrong image.

Taking a look at the console logs I can see that the replacement process is being doing fine. One difference I noticed is in the `maven.build.properties` file which is inside the submodule having the issue. I think this file was created at packaging the submodule. When I package the project locally the property `build.number` in this file is the one I passed in the command line but when I package it with jenkins, the value in this file is `latest`.

I don't know if it is an issue about Jenkins, multibranch pipeline, the way we are archiving the files, the location the file is archived or about maven.

NOTE: I had this project working fine before, using a non multibranch pipeline. After a server migration we started to use multibranch pipeline and we did not realize that it was failing until now.

Comment: This may just be a type in your Maven command in Jenkins.

Comment: Is there any error in your pipeline ?
Your variable seems to be wrong, try to replace `BUILD_NUMER` with `BUILD_NUMBER`

Comment: Hi, it is a typo here in the post. I'm using ${BUILD_NUMBER} in my Jenkinsfile.